# sort dataframe by substring in columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a DataFrame with three columns and one million rows. I want to sort the DataFrame into thirty-five separate DataFrames based on a pattern from the strings in the third column. This requires a few steps, which I'm struggling with.

First, I need to get the substrings from each of the one million rows in the third column. The substrings have the regex form r'\'\d\d'. There will be multiple in each cell. I need to sort the DataFrame according to the smallest number (\d\d) in each cell.

I am stuck at an early step. I am using the following line of code to try to extract the regex pattern from each row in the third column ('Review').

```
print(df['Review'].str.extractall(r'\'\d\d'), expand = True)
```

As output, I get:

```
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

Help?

Comment: `"ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups"` Well, have you tried adding capture groups to the regex?

Comment: sorry if this is super dumb: isn't r'\'\d\d' a capture group?

Comment: No, it isn't. Capture groups are denoted with parentheses.

Comment: well, isn't it the case that extractall() takes regex as its argument, so whatever's between those parens is treated as a capture group? or do I need an extra set of parens after the r?

Comment: `df['Review'].str.extract(r'(\'\d\d)', expand=True)`

Comment: thanks you—sorry this was so basic

Answer (score 1):

As @DeepSpace mentioned the Regex you included doesn't contain a capture group. Capture groups are denoted by parentheses *in* the regex.

Try

```
print(df['Review'].str.extractall(r'(\'\d\d)'))
```

And check out some resources on regular expressions like https://regexone.com/.